# check if an external url exists. cors-react

Tags: reactjs, url

I am working locally with react and a nodejs server. I have configured my nodejs server to communicate with react and it works.

From react I want to check if external urls (for example youtube) exist, but the cors error always jumps.

I have tried with axios, XMLHttpRequest, fetch and I have used the header : 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',

I can remove the cors validation from the browser for testing, but what happens when I upload it to the server?

How can I check if an image, page, video... on an external server exists?

Comment: if the external server doesnt allow it then you wont be able to do so. Cors must be enabled on that server.

Comment: CORS is only applied when you try to do it directly from your browser. Then you can create your own server, create an API endpoint to check if a URL exists, and then, from your react page, you send requests to your API and your API check the page existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is only applied when you try to do it directly from your browser. Then you can create your own server, create an API endpoint to check if a URL exists, and then, from your react page, you send requests to your API and your API check the page existence. –  (by Pipe)